# Protocol method won't execute in another view controller

Tags: swift, delegates, swift-protocols

I have a rootviewcontroller which i am using to subclass all of my view controllers in this there is a protocol with a method that i'm trying to execute the view controller is set up like so

**Root View Controller**

```
protocol RootControllerDelegate: class {

    func refreshTheTable(sender: AnyObject)

}

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var rootDelegate : RootControllerDelegate?
}
```

So i have a button with an IBAction in one of my view controllers which is suppose to fire the delegate function.

**View Controller to fire the function**

```
// You can see here I'm subclassing the root view controller

class FiltersViewController: RootViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBAction func doneButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

        rootDelegate?.refreshTheTable(sender)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

So in this view controller i have set up the delegate in the viewdidAppear and also called the function just to print something for now just for testing purposes but nothing happens.

**View Controller where function should execute**

```
class TopStoriesViewController: RootViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ReminderViewControllerDelegate, DZNEmptyDataSetDelegate, DZNEmptyDataSetSource, RootControllerDelegate { 

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(false)

       rootDelegate = self
   }


    func refreshTheTable(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("dsdsdsds")
    }
}
```

But nothing seems to be happening... When i debug it as well it doesn't even execute the function as well

Answer (score 1):

You have two classes and two different delegates assigned.

- First class, `FiltersViewController`, which should fire the delegate
  method, has nil. So nothing is set to handle the method.
- Second class, `TopStoriesViewController`, which should handle the
  method, has delegate. But, in this class you don't call delegate's methods, you are calling them in the class `FiltersViewController`.

You have to set `TopStoriesViewController` (which has the delegate methods implemented) as the delegate of `FiltersViewController` (which fires up delegate methods). From your code, the delegate assigned in `TopStoriesViewController` is not needed.